# how to find which row is significantly different

Tags: r, anova, tukey-hsd-test

I have a data which looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 20L, 15L, 19L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 22L, 
21L), .Label = c("A", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAB", "AAAABB", 
"AAAABBB", "AAAABBBB", "AAATTF", "AABBBBBB", "AABBBBBBB", "AACCBBB", 
"AACFBB", "AACFFBB", "AAHHT", "AAHTRE", "AAILT", "AAQERE", "AAQZER", 
"AAZZE", "HHILOP", "KKOLI"), class = "factor"), intensity1 = c(9.2493e+10, 
22191000, 8023700, 11697000, 7174600, 4607700, 1718000, 495600, 
0, 0, 899680, 2511500, 0, 0, 824860, 142870, 214920, 0, 155570, 
144230, 0, 11162000), intensity2 = c(5.182e+10, 23191000, 1833300, 
15123000, 5286200, 3962300, 4160700, 3877800, 0, 0, 421740, 0, 
0, 0, 3290200, 1346600, 1497100, 0, 1185000, 902350, 0, 0), intensity3 = c(1.0304e+11, 
19558000, 26232000, 10694000, 7608100, 4960100, 0, 456010, 0, 
0, 3432700, 3372200, 3649700, 0, 769020, 119060, 960980, 577520, 
153860, 425070, 0, 0), intensity4 = c(8.6731e+10, 34212000, 15430000, 
26206000, 11916000, 5104700, 240650, 215880, 0, 0, 860790, 2853500, 
0, 0, 1526800, 117800, 435430, 311020, 134200, 0, 0, 15570000
), intensity5 = c(8.0643e+10, 16912000, 7277900, 11909000, 5147300, 
3826800, 1645200, 810120, 0, 0, 830610, 2687400, 1590400, 186740, 
3220300, 360170, 431150, 0, 384800, 333930, 0, 0), intensity6 = c(1.0755e+11, 
25127000, 9013300, 16737000, 9711000, 5459500, 223830, 159780, 
0, 0, 2806900, 6519900, 8388500, 0, 674750, 118660, 550450, 625730, 
144630, 0, 0, 18348000)), .Names = c("ID", "intensity1", "intensity2", 
"intensity3", "intensity4", "intensity5", "intensity6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

These are the measurement of Mass spectrometry from 6 samples. The first three are replicate of the first sample (intensity1, intensity2 and intensity3) and the second 3 samples are the replicate for the second sample (intensity4, intensity5 and intensity6). I want to know which one of the row data are significantly different than the rest.

Comment: You seem to be rather interested in anomaly detection then hypothesis testing, aren’t you?

Comment: @Tim♦ the hypothesis testing is also important because of the fact that one should know which ones are statistically significantly different than others

Comment: What for do you need to know this?

Comment: @Tim♦. which rows are upregulated and which ones are down regulated